# Navigation bar with searchBarController of UITabBarController flickering on changing the color of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

The bottom line of navigation bar (having a search controller) is flickering when I scroll in iOS (iPhone X). Tried many solutions, but none of them worked. Here is my code:

(I'm not using storyboard)

**AppDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow()
    let viewCtrl = TabController()
    let navCtrl = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewCtrl)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navCtrl
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

**TabBarController**

```
class TabController: UITabBarController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.viewControllers = [ViewController()]
        self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        return cell
    }

}
```

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same issue, and I am thinking is a bug from Apple. But anyway, if it helps, making the navigation bar `isTranslucent = false` can help to avoid that ugly behaviour.